# Return data to ajax from java Servlet method doGet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have my function ajax like this :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "associer_type_flux", // It's  my servlet
        dataType : "xml",
        type : "GET",
        data : { },
        success: function(response){
            alert("fine");
        },
        error:  function(data, status, er){
            alert(data+"_"+status+"_"+er);
        }
    });
```

And my method doGet in my servlet like this :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String forward = ""; 
    try {           
        String fluxXML = "";
        ServicesCodeTypeFluxGlobaux servicesCodeTypeFluxGlobaux = new ServicesCodeTypeFluxGlobauxImpl();

            fluxXML = "<lescodetypeflux>";

            fluxXML += "</lescodetypeflux>";
            PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();
            printWriter.println(fluxXML);

        }
        forward = "/associerCode/accueil_association.jsp";
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(forward).forward(request, response);           
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        forward = "/erreur.jsp";
        request.setAttribute("msg", e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

So my problem is that, I cant get data in my jsp .. But i don't know how get this data or return this data from doGet method .. Now I have an alert Error ..

Thx

Comment: Open you browser network console and check what is going on.

Comment: I have this error : status : parserror ... :'( .. No idea

Comment: Look at the response. What's the content?

Comment: Response in Java or  Ajax .. If in Ajax I can't get it because .. say me status : parsererror

Comment: The network console will have information on each request and response including headers and body. I doubt that's what the parse error is. Just select the response and see what's in it. Alternatively, use a different client (maybe in Java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestion to make it work -

1. don't forget to set mime type in your case "text/xml" or "application/xml"
2. You can not use both together out.println() and requestdispatcher as it will throw exception. out.println() will print the value in response body but request dispatcher will redirect you to some other page and incase of ajax what you will get is the whole content of the page where you redirected.

so in your case you should only use out.println()

So your final code should look like this -

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    String forward = ""; 
    try {           
        String fluxXML = "";
        ServicesCodeTypeFluxGlobaux servicesCodeTypeFluxGlobaux = new ServicesCodeTypeFluxGlobauxImpl();

            fluxXML = "<lescodetypeflux>";

            fluxXML += "</lescodetypeflux>";
            PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();
            printWriter.println(fluxXML);
            printWriter.close();
        }        
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //print xml with error value
    }       
}
```

Comment: OK I see .. So if I do it I have my page with XML return .. And how can i do for see my page JSP with table etc ..  I get this :      <lescodetypeflux>
- <lecodetypeflux>
  <idcodetypeflux>1101</idcodetypeflux>
  </lecodetypeflux>
</lescodetypeflux>

Comment: You can not get data as well as do request dispatch in a single click. You can try some other alternative like - 
1. first redirect to the page where you are displaying data in to the table and then make ajax call to get data.
2. You make ajax call get data and then with javascript create table in the div where you want to show.